# have changed a folder to www-data, but apache is still not able to create file on it

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

I have several folder that I use for uploading file from PHP.
I have change the group permission of this folder to www-data ( a group that apache2 also shares ). but somehow I am still not able to upload a file to it. I think I miss some small thing, but I'm not really sure what it is. Any idea?

Below is my folder configuration :

```
ubuntu@myip:~/tweb/Server/myserver/assets$ ls -l 
total 112

drwxrwsr-x 2 ubuntu www-data  4096 Aug 23 10:02 attachment
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu www-data  4096 Aug 23 10:02 photo
drwxrwsr-x 2 ubuntu www-data 16384 Aug 23 10:02 logo
```

Below is the screenshot of the apache instance.

```
ubuntu@myip:~/tweb/Server/myserver/assets$ ps aux | grep apache

www-data  2324  0.1  3.8 285548 23036 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2326  0.0  3.9 287104 23888 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2327  0.1  3.8 285560 23152 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2328  0.1  3.8 285544 23140 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2329  0.1  3.8 285828 23276 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2332  0.0  1.6 276284 10076 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2333  0.0  3.3 282852 20520 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2334  0.0  1.6 276284 10076 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2336  0.0  1.6 276276  9984 ?        S    03:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2714  0.0  1.4 275624  8504 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    2718  0.0  0.1   8128   660 pts/0    S+   03:41   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
root     22942  0.0  2.6 275592 15904 ?        Ss   Aug23   0:14 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

When I checked to which group www-data is belong to, it seems that the user is belong to www-data group.

```
groups www-data
www-data : www-data
```

Comment: Have you checked web server & PHP logs?

Comment: yes. already check the username who run the php script and it also said as "www-data". Using : $current_user = trim(shell_exec('whoami'));

Comment: What errors did the logs have in them?

Comment: The PHP code works correctly, so it opens a form with multipart file etc. right?

Answer (score 1):

In order to write to a new file in a directory, the user needs write permission on the directory. It *also* needs scan ('x') permission on *every one* of that directory's parent directories.